# Raspbian or Raspbian Lite for Cross Compiling Qt

Tags: raspbian, qt, raspbian-stretch, raspbian-lite

I try to follow this guide https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS for cross-compiling Qt. The instructions don't specify whether I need to use the Desktop version or whether also the lite version would do.

Would Raspbian lite work?

Comment: Does the answer help you? If so, please accept it with a click on the tick on its left side. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to run Qt without X11 Raspbian Lite is perfect. If you intend to run on X11 then you're probably better off using Raspbian.